# Trying to make a basic Ping tool with a simple GUI, However at the moment the ping button does nothing even though I've defined it to have an action

Tags: powershell, user-interface

However at the moment the ping button does nothing even though I've defined it to have an action.

```
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Data Entry Form'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,400)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(35,35)
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,23)
$Button.Text = "Ping"
$Button.Add_Click($Button_Click)

$Form.Controls.Add($Button)
$form.showdialog()

$Button_Click = $pinger

$pinger = Ping 8.8.8.8 -t > C:\Tools\Pingtoool.txt

$form.Topmost = $true
$form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
$result = $form.ShowDialog()
```

If anyone could take a look and perhaps recommend better ways of doing things, I would gladly be all ears.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't include pictures of code; include your code instead

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realize.

Comment: @HarryGoodall Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69726724/edit) and include the code instead of the screenshot, will help you with the formatting if needed.

Comment: I've eddited it :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to store your event as a `scriptblock`, in addition to this, the `scriptblock` should be defined before adding it to the `Click` event of your button. I have added a few modifications to your code, test it now :)

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms, System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Data Entry Form'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,400)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$form.Topmost = $true

$pingEvent = {
    $file = New-TemporaryFile
    Test-Connection 8.8.8.8 | Out-File $file
    notepad.exe $file
}

$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(35,35)
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,23)
$Button.Text = "Ping"
$Button.Add_Click($pingEvent)
$Form.Controls.Add($Button)

$form.Add_Shown({$Button.Select()})
$result = $form.ShowDialog()
```

A few considerations:

- `ping -t` would make your GUI freeze since it will run until being manually stopped.
- `ping` has been changed for `Test-Connection` as it's PowerShell's built-in cmdlet intended for pinging.
- `$pinger = Ping 8.8.8.8 -t > C:\Tools\Pingtoool.txt` is being executed at the moment this line is interpreted, if you want to execute this line when clicking the button you would store the code as a `scriptblock`:

```
$pinger = { Ping 8.8.8.8 -t > C:\Tools\Pingtoool.txt }
$Button.Add_Click($pinger)
```

It can be also simplified to:

```
$Button.Add_Click({
    Ping 8.8.8.8 -t > C:\Tools\Pingtoool.txt
})
```

- On line `$Button.Add_Click($Button_Click)`, `$Button_Click` is being added as an `event` before being defined which is why when you click nothing happens (in addition to what was mentioned before, the `event` not being a `scriptblock`).

Comment: I don't think `New-TemporaryFile` is going to do what OP intends - `C:\Tools\Pingtoool.txt` doesn't sound very temporary :-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I know, the code was intended to demonstrate why his code was failing. I should also should have pointed out that the GUI would freeze since he is using `-t` on `ping`. I'll edit my answer, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon My only issue using Test-Connection is, this Pinger is 1) mean to ping for a varying length of time depending on how long the user leaves it on for, and 2) test connection doesn't give results like response times, something that's very important for the return side of it.

Comment: @HarryGoodall my answer was meant to explain you what you were doing wrong on your code and how to fix it not to argue about `ping` vs `Test-Connection`....

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon My apologies I mean more, are you aware of a way I could use Test-Connection while still getting the parameters I need?.

Comment: @HarryGoodall for point 1. pinging a host depending on how long the users want can be done with a while loop, however again, as I explained, that would make the GUI freeze and become unresponsive (you would need to ping on a separate Thread i.e.: using `Start-Job` and adding a `Stop Ping` button to know when to end the Job). For point 2. `Test-Connection` does return the exact same values as the normal `ping` the only difference is that it will not show by default the TTL, you would need to select that property.